# Print description from Report Properties to report footer.

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to use the Description Field in the Report Properties and print that on the footer? I have looked and did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can I think but it is a lame answer.  You need to deploy the report and then check the catalog table in the ReportServer database of what you just deployed.  As far as I have ever read or tried the 'Globals' and 'ReportItems' do not contain it, yet the database does.  EG:

1. Create a variable named ReportName and have it's default be

   ```
   =Globals!ReportName
   ```

   Ensure the parameter is set to 'Internal' as you don't want users to see it.
2. Create a data set to get the name and description of your report

   ```
    SELECT Name, Description 
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog  
    WHERE Name = @ReportName
   ```
3. Drag and drop the 'Description' of the new dataset to your Report Footer.

**You must first deploy the report for the item to be in the catalog as the database is what is on the hosted server.  Not what you are working on in BIDS.**